# Visual flow formula not working with text fields

Tags: visual-workflow

In my flow I'm trying to concatenate two text values `'[Autoreply] ' & {!MyEmailTemplate.Subject}` and create a new record with joined string in one of the fields.

Everything works great until subject of my email template has merge fields, example:

- `Hello someone` works great
- `Hello {!Lead.firstName}` doesn't work and for joined string formula returns completely blank value without showing any errors.

I tried to use `SUBSTITUTE({!MyEmailTemplate.Subject}, '{!', '%')` and `htmlencode` without any luck, same behavior - formula returns empty text.

Is it supposed to be this way? Any workarounds to bypass merge fields and paste as text?

**UPDATE**

Here's an example. I created a simple flow which accepts variable `input`, joins text in the formula:

[image]

and assigns formula result to an `output` variable:

[image]

Flow has only the assignment element and nothing else. And then I'm triggering it in the process builder:
[image]

And it even doesn't let me save the process. If instead I use just `hi` as an input everything works!

Comment: Can you post screen shot of flow where you populate merge fields

Comment: @Reshma thanks for reply, I've updated the description. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I think it doesn't like you mixing the string and variable in the same input value. You would normally have to have PB pass a Reference to the contact or lead field that you needed.

Comment: @DaveHumm that's the thing, I can't. I'm passing emailtemplate as an input which has merge fields and I want to parse it as a plain text or populate the fields.